# How to find then Update a user record Mongo/Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting user.update is not a function when running this code. I have been unable to find good mongo/mongoose documentations online.

````
  //Add Event
  app.post("/addEvent", (req, res, next) => {
    const event = req.body.event;
    console.log(req.user.id);
    console.log(event);
    User.find({ _id: req.user.id }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return next(err);
      }
      if (user) {
        user.update(
          {
            _id: req.user.id
          },
          {
            $push: { events: event }
          }
        );
      }
      res.end();
    });
  });
};```
````

Comment: Does code works fine w/o `user.update` part? `console.log` shows existing user correctly? And what's stored in `event` variable? Code of http request?

Comment: Yeah code works fine otherwise

Comment: if so, why no using `findAndUpdate` with correct options? [https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate]

Comment: I’m just unclear why this isn’t working

Comment: because you trying to `update` result doc. And `update` options requires `Model` instead of `doc` also, document result isn't just the same, as array/object. Also `find` return array of docs, not just one doc. You should using `findOne` instead. You could check it, via `{lean: false/true}` options. And if you'd like to update `document` you should trigger `.save` middleware

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I guess it might help you.

```
  app.post("/addEvent", (req, res, next) => {
    const event = req.body.event;
    console.log(req.user.id);
    console.log(event);
    User.findById({ req.user.id }, async function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return next(err);
      }
      if (user) {
        User.updateOne(
          {
            _id: req.user.id
          },
          {
            $push: { events: event }
          }
        );
      }
      res.end();
    });
  });
};
```

I also recommended you using [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) or [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) with necessary options in your case. Or `findOne` instead of `find` because find returns you [array] of documents, instead of one document, so if you'll be using `async/await` like that:

```
const docs = Users.find(query,callback)
```

They only way to access necessary document will be `docs[n]` where `n` is number of doc in resulting array.